# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, apache, docker, mysqli, containers

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/login.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/login.php on line 8
```

Code

```
<?php
$servername = "172.17.0.2:3306";
$username = "mysql_user";
$password = "mysql_password";
$dbname = "invoice";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
?>
```

I am running it from php:7.0-apache docker container and I have already installed mysqli extension using following command:

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli 
docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
apachectl restart
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You are also mixing the mysql_ and mysqli_ api's.

Comment: You can also do phpinfo() to verify if mysqli extension is enabled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the path to php extension_dir correct or not.
if it's not correct or there is not a path, 
then add absolute path of mysqli.so in php.ini ,

In my case, mysqli.so was at `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012`

You have to add ,

```
extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mysqli.so
```

in your php.ini.